# How can I simplify the test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test my method `IOConsoleWriterImpl.displayAllClientsInfo(List<ClientEntity> clients)` that it prints data.

`displayAllClientsInfo` has approximately the following structure:

```
for (ClientEntity client : clients) {
    System.out.println(client.getName());
    List<AccountEntity> accounts = client.getAccountEntities();
    for (AccountEntity account : accounts){
        System.out.println(account.getLogin());
    }
}
```

So, as I understand it, in order to mock two foreach loops (with Mockito), I need to mock two iterators.

There is the test:

```
    @Test
    void isDisplayAllClientsInfoPrintData() {
        //Given
        List<ClientEntity> clients = mock(List.class);
        List<AccountEntity> accounts = mock(List.class);
        Iterator<ClientEntity> clientIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
        Iterator<AccountEntity> accountIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
        ClientEntity client = mock(ClientEntity.class);
        AccountEntity account = mock(AccountEntity.class);

        when(clientIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
        when(clientIterator.next()).thenReturn(client);
        when(clients.iterator()).thenReturn(clientIterator);

        when(accountIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
        when(accountIterator.next()).thenReturn(account);
        when(accounts.iterator()).thenReturn(accountIterator);

        when(clients.size()).thenReturn(1);
        when(client.getAccountEntities()).thenReturn(accounts);
        when(client.getId()).thenReturn(1L);
        when(client.getEmail()).thenReturn("client@example.com");
        when(client.getName()).thenReturn("John Smith");
        when(account.getId()).thenReturn(2L);
        when(account.getCreated()).thenReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59));
        when(account.getLogin()).thenReturn("JSmith");
        when(account.getPassword()).thenReturn("zzwvp0d9");

        //When
        IOConsoleWriter io = new IOConsoleWriterImpl();
        io.displayAllClientsInfo(clients);

        //Then
        String output = outputStream.toString();
        assertAll(
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(1))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("client@example.com")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("John Smith")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(Long.toString(2))),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains(LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59).toString())),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("JSmith")),
                () -> assertTrue(output.contains("zzwvp0d9"))
        );
    }
```

I believe that there is a nice way to avoid code duplication (I mean the second and third paragraphs of the test). Or I should not worry and everything is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all looks a little bit awkward so I can understand your thinking about how to simplify it.

You could just pass in an **actual** list of `ClientInfo` instances rather than a mocked one. For example:

```
List<ClientInfo> clientInfos = new ArrayList<>();

clients.add(new ClientInfo(1L, "client@example.com", "John Smith", 
    Arrays.asList(
        new Account(2L, LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59), "JSmith", "zzwvp0d9"))
    )
);

io.displayAllClientsInfo(clients);
```

But that seems obvious so perhaps there is some reason why you are not already doing that (maybe constructing these classes is a bit awkward or overly verbose).

Alternatively, you could side step the 'test setup' awkwardness by making your code more test friendly. For example, you could extract the 'write' responsibility out of the `IOConsoleWriterImpl` into an interface which you inject into `IOConsoleWriterImpl`. Something like this:

```
// extract from IOConsoleWriterImpl

public IOConsoleWriterImpl(Writer writer) {
    this.writer = writer;
}

public void displayAllClientsInfo(ClientEntity clients) {
    for (ClientEntity client : clients) {
        System.out.println(client.getName());
        List<AccountEntity> accounts = client.getAccountEntities();
        for (AccountEntity account : accounts){
            writer.write(account.getLogin());
        }
    }
}

// a new interface to extract the 'writing' behaviour out of IOConsoleWriterImpl
public interface Writer {
    void write(String output);
}

// a sysout implementation of the Writer interface
public class SystemOutWriter implements Writer {
    @Override
    public void write(String output) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Then in your test case you could inject a mocked `Writer`into the `IOConsoleWriter` and verify that it is called with your expected state.

```
Writer writer = Mockito.mock(Writer.class);
IOConsoleWriter io = new IOConsoleWriterImpl(writer);

io.displayAllClientsInfo(clients);

Mockito.verify(writer).write(...);
```

Similarly, you could provide a stubbed implementation of `Writer` which records what it is given and then assert on the contents of this stub. For Example:

```
public class RecordingWriter implements Writer {
    private List<String> recordings = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void write(String output) {
        recordings.add(output);
    }

    public boolean contains(String incoming) {
        return recordings.contains(incoming);
    }
}

RecordingWriter writer = new RecordingWriter();
IOConsoleWriter io = new IOConsoleWriterImpl(writer);

io.displayAllClientsInfo(clients);

assertAll(
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains(Long.toString(1))),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains("client@example.com")),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains("John Smith")),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains(Long.toString(2))),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains(LocalDateTime.of(2017,5,25,12,59).toString())),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains("JSmith")),
            () -> assertTrue(writer.contains("zzwvp0d9"))
    );
```

**Update 1**: based on your comment and the links you provided to the actual classes at play here.

It looks like `IOConsoleWriterImpl.displayAllClientsInfo()` has two responsibilities:

- Interrogating a collection of `ClientInfo` and working out what to print
- Printing output (including headers and formatting)

This makes me think that extracting a `Writer` interface would offer a few benefits:

- Promotes SRP for `IOConsoleWriterImpl`
- Simplifies `IOConsoleWriterImpl`
- Facilitates simpler testing for `IOConsoleWriterImpl` since `IOConsoleWriterTest` could focus on *just the client interrogation responsibilties*
- Facilitates simpler testing of the 'writing' behaviour; you could write a `SystemOutWriterTest` which focuses on *just the writer responsibilties*

However, what you've already done is ok; it provides good coverage of `IOConsoleWriterImpl.displayAllClientsInfo()` and although it is quite verbose it is still readable.

In summary, I'd suggest that passing in an actual List is the simplest change that is (a) functionally equivalent to what you currently have and (b) involves less setup / is easier to read. Beyond that my suggestion about extracting the 'writing' behaviour behind a new interface will simplify `IOConsoleWriterImpl` and make your testing more fine grained (with each test case being, perhaps, smaller and easier to reason about) and this change would - I think - be quite simple to make. Of course, your appetite for change might be different ;) and the benefits here aren't sufficiently compelling to demand this change.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave very useful ideas. I agree that in this case the problem should be solved not by test but by changing the source code.

I didn't pass in an actual list because I thought it is wrong way in testing...
I would like to take this opportunity to show the entire classes [IOConsoleWriterImpl](https://gist.github.com/Tw0l4nd/7340de5a33e27173759c4fbb2f14b00a),
 [IOConsoleWriterImplTest](https://gist.github.com/Tw0l4nd/e29a262d8df2ff14937c249c1ef6fecc).
Maybe you can give some more valuable recommendations :)

Comment: @Woland I've had a look at those links and updated my answer.

Comment: I will try to extracting the 'writing' behavior :) How about you look at the whole project? (it is small, educational)  I wrote earlier on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but no one answered and I deleted the post. If you agree, I'll write a post right now. :)

Comment: If you post it I'll try to have a look sometime over the next ~day. Can't promise I'll have the time but I'll try :)

Comment: [The question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358636/need-code-review-on-simple-educational-task). You are welcome! :)

Comment: @Woland when I click on [that link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358636/need-code-review-on-simple-educational-task) I get a 404.

Comment: It was wrong place... I forgot about codereview.stackexchange.com. [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177242/simple-educational-task-on-hibernate)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. I want to know should I wait for a response or delete the post :)

Comment: Hi! Where are you? :) **[link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177242/educational-hibernate-project-to-create-delete-change-accounts)**

Comment: I had a quick look but I won't have time to perform a review of that code.

Comment: Nobody wants :(